# Recovering RAID: what's wrong?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have to recover my md0 RAID software with linux.

Today I've bought 4 disks,all new,all the same type and size.

I have removed the old disk using:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdd2
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdd2
```

changed with the new ones:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdd2
```

Waited for rebuild and it works

Same thing for disk n°3 (sdc2)

On the sdb2 change the RAID started  to give a lot of errors,"sector read failed etc" but not on sdb2, but on sdc2 when sdb2 was rebuilding!
Then the system put my ext4 raid in R/O mode.

So I rebooted in single user mode(slackware can from initrd) and try to rebuild,of course before removing sdc2(faulty disk) and sdb2(incomplete
resync).

I put the old sdb2 disk and tried to start; the array failed.
Tried to add sdb2 to the array; itfailed, and told me to stop and reassemble.

I did

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0 
mdadm /dev/md0 --assemble /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdd2
```

I want to start with 3 disks,then add sdc2 and complete the array.
But it failed considering the sda2 and sdd ok,but mark sdb2 as..removed.
How to readd sdb2 and rebuild my array?

Comment: Now is a good time to realise that RAID is not a Backup.  If you had lost the content of the raid, would you have been able to recover?

Comment: I know raid is not a backup,but save only from disk crash,the problem happen when you have 4 disk,replace 1 for increase size(then I will replace other 3),but during the resync one of the disk fault!So 1 fault,1 resync=2 4-2 =2 and raid5 don't start with two disk :),fortunately i didn't wipe the old disk and i can rebuild the raid,p.s=i know i can use two spare disk on raid5 but my server has only 4 slot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found,the old sdb2 was marked as faulty
so the only solution was/is:

Boot from livecd or from initrd, and do:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --stop 
mdadm /dev/md0 --assemble --force /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2
```

This will add all disks except the "faulty" drive, but will start md0

Then we will add the missing drive:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb2
```

The array is reconstructing then, and the system works by now.

WARNING: after this "procedure" i've lost my lvm,because lvm don't recognize the md0 anymore,pvscan give error(id changed or something)
so the best solution is..backup.